# Why is 11D supergravity part of M-theory?

Tags: string-theory, field-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, supergravity

11D Supergravity is a field theory, while the varieties of superstring theories is not. Why would [M-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory) include theories of two different framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The five superstring theories correspond uniquely to the five possible SUGRA theories in 10d as their low-energy effective theories.
2. The five SUGRA theories can be obtained by various styles of dimensional reduction from the unique 11d SUGRA theory.

Therefore, M-theory is conjectured to be a "stringy" 11d theory that can be reduced to the five superstring theories in similar limits and that has 11d SUGRA as its low-energy effective theory.

Answer (score 0):

Superstring theory: 6D hyperspace + common 4D = 10D spacetime.
Supergravity theory: 7D hs + 4D = 11D st
M-theory includes both superstring & Supergravity theories yet mostly promotes 11D.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423268)